# Django Unicode Errors

Tags: python, django, unicode

I have a form that a user can submit and it's data will be added for everyone to see. (take a comments section for example.)

Someone made a comment with this face: ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Now, whenever a user tries to view the page, a 500 error is returned.

`'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-3: ordinal not in range(128)`

Besides deleting the comment through the console, what can I do to properly encode these?

Comment: I have a dependency that hasn't been converted to Python 3 yet.

Comment: The behaviour is a bug by itself, try to use -3 command line switch or the `unicodenazi` module to find out the culprit, most probably you yourself are concatenating unicode strings with the comment, while the comment string itself is a 8-bit bytestring.

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Where does the error occur. You probably use `str` somewhere, where you should use  `unicode`. Django in principle is unicode capable.

Comment: @Magic either use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in your comments model ( or where ever this string is being returned ) or prefix that string with a `u` like `u"User made this comment: {}".format(comment)`

Comment: Can you post the view code?

Comment: Python 3 is not a magic fix for Unicode problems and is very unlikely to help here. (Both Python 2 and 3 have both byte strings and unicode strings, they're just spelled differently and Python 3 uses the unicode string type for more datatypes that could be either. The actual main difference is that Python 3 is stricter about what happens when string types are combined or misused. This doesn't stop errors happening, it just means the error gets reported earlier.)

Comment: In any case, you need to get a stack trace including the line of the code that's throwing the error so you can fix it. Somewhere, you are writing user-submitted content (which has non-ASCII content in it) to something that can only take bytes, without encoding the unicode to bytes first. This won't be in a template because Django encodes there automatically, but your app might be trying to write it to a file or call `str` on it or something.